# How to Trim a Leading and Trailing char in regular expressions?

Tags: regex

I have a requirement to trim a leading and trailing character of a fixed length column.

Ex: I have column `IdNumber` which is of fixed length say 11, with below values

`X3343438594`
`7743438534X`

I want to trim the leading and trailing X, and result should look like this.

`3343438594`
`7743438534`

Comment: Pattern: ^X+|X+$, replaced by : null

Comment: `^X|X$`, and replace with `<blank>`, This is working for me. But to be specific, my requirement is something like this. i.e. I have to trim only values which is of 11 chars length only and starts with X123....... or 123..........X. sorry for not being specific earlier

Comment: Update your question with more examples

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Search: ^X(?=\d{11}$)|(?<=^\d{11})X$
Replace: <blank>
```

Regex breakdown:

- `^X` means "start of input then X"
- `(?=\d{11}$)` means "followed by 11 digits then end"
- `|` means "logical OR"
- `(?<=^\d{11})` means "preceded by start then 11 digits"
- `X$` means "X then end of input"

You want to delete all matches, so replace them with nothing.

Comment: Thanks @Bohemiam, This is working for me. But to be specific, my requirement is something like this. i.e. I have to trim only values which is of 11 chars length and starts with X123....... or 123..........X.   sorry for not being specific earlier

Comment: @kriti I have added assertions so it will only work as you need

Answer (score 0):

```js
var re = /(?=^X|X$)(([A-Z])(\d{10})(\s)(\d{10})([A-Z]))/; 
var str = 'X3343438594 7743438534X';
var subst = '$3$4$5'; 
var result = str.replace(re, subst);
alert(result);
```

The regex first asserts that the string should have an X at the beginning or at the end, regardless of the length of your data (not necessarily 11 characters).  If that's the case, it tests for a pattern that starts with one letter, followed by 10 digits (totalling 11 characters), then a space, then ten digits followed by one letter (another 11 characters).